# What to do if clause is disabled in a switch statement?

Tags: switch-statement

I'm sorry for the title, I wasn't sure what to call it.

My problem is this, I have a switch statement which randomly chooses a question type as so:

```
questionType[count] = rad.nextInt(4);

        switch (questionType[count])
        {
        case 0:

                questionArray[count] = new Times(count + 1);
                ((Times) questionArray[count]).askQuestion(question);
                break;

        case 1:

                questionArray[count] = new Add(count + 1);
                ((Add) questionArray[count]).askQuestion(question);
                break;

        case 2:

                questionArray[count] = new Minus(count + 1);
                ((Minus) questionArray[count]).askQuestion(question);
                break;

        case 3:

            questionArray[count] = new Divide(count + 1);
            ((Divide) questionArray[count]).askQuestion(question);
            break;

        }
```

What this does is randomly choose a question and then add it to the next array, here is the pesudocode version:

```
questionType = random(4)

case questionType == 0
do something
break

case questionType == 1
do something
break

case questionType == 2
do something
break

case questionType == 3
do something
break;
```

Now lets say I do not want any 1's or 2's, how do I put that into effect? I was thinking something along the lines of this:

```
 START:

     questionType = random(4)


        case questionType == 0
    if(0 enabled)
    {
        do something

        break
    }

        case questionType == 1
    if(1 enabled)
    {
        do something
        break
    }

        case questionType == 2
    if(2 enabled)
    {
        do something
        break
    }


        case questionType == 3
    if(3 enabled)
    {
        do something
        break;
    }
else goto start
```

But this is very inefficient code and uses a goto, what are the alternatives?

Comment: Couldn't you just do your check before the switch statement rather than checking if enabled within each case?

Comment: I could, but that wouldn't be much use unless I made a switch statement for every combination.

Comment: I don't think I'm 100% clear on what you're trying to accomplish. However, what if you moved the switch statement to a method that returned a boolean (True if it added a question or whatever your 'do something' does, otherwise false)? Then you can loop and call that method until you're done (not enough info to tell you what to check for that). Note, from your code though, if you loop and keep trying random numbers in an attempt to get enabled questions you could have problems...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few ways of implementing but
if you had a store of questions, and whether they were enabled.
Then extract enabled from that and use it's count as the argument for rad.
so you enabled Questions would be 3 & 4 but would occupy positions 0 & 1 in the list of enabled questions.

Answer (score 0):

'Enabled' global or static array of boolean.  Loop around the random number generation until you get an index that addresses a true value in the 'Enabled' array.  Keep a count of the total number of enabled choices because of the special case - '0' - return an error or raise exception to prevent endless looping in a futile attempt to find a valid choice.